# Can read from database but not insert

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem using Visual Studio 2010. I am using a Service-based database (`.mdf`). The problem is that I can get information from the database but I can't insert information to the database.

When I add information to the database the rows are affected but when I open the table in Visual Studios Server Explorer nothing have changed.

There is nothing wrong with the code I have written, because it works in my schools computers.

Is there any settings I have to change?

Comment: I find that when that happens you are usually looking in the wrong place.  Take a look at your connection string and make sure you are checking for the data there, and not somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you're using `AttachDbFileName=......`  in your connection string - correct?

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `YourDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...